# create new column in dataframe that subtract a column with list from another column with list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains 2 column and I would like to create a third one that remove values in first column contained in 2nd column:

| list_first | list_second |
| --- | --- |
| [1,2,3] | [3] |
| [4,7,8,9] | [4,9] |

output desired

| list_first | list_second | list_third |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [1,2,3] | [3] | [1,2] |
| [4,7,8,9] | [4,9] | [7,8] |

Comment: the question is how to create this third column. I have tried different things but none of them are working, and I usualy get an error :  unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: yeah you should've put that in the question body along with your attempts... Some people downvote questions because of that, you know.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension for difference between lists:

```
df['list_third'] = [[x for x in a if x not in b] for a, b in df[['fist_first','list_second']].to_numpy()]
print (df)
     fist_first list_second list_third
0     [1, 2, 3]         [3]     [1, 2]
1  [4, 7, 8, 9]      [4, 9]     [7, 8]
```